# How to write to Excel using MVC and EF Code First - Best Practices

Tags: asp.net-mvc, excel, entity-framework

Vs'12 asp.net C# MVC, Internet Application Template, Kendo UI, EF Code First

What I am trying to do is use all my `dataModels` together and Build an `Excel` file, nicely formatted and all that good stuff - placing certain data into certain fields.*These files would be fairly complex, - adding and checking checkboxes In Excel, creating boxes around fields other formatting*

Now from what i can tell were exporting data from HTML into excel, however this is not something i would want, the only other way I can think of is to run `C#` code from a `controller` through a `class`, and then make it downloadable / and or export it?

Is this a "Best Practice" and if not what is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create your Excel to a `byte[]` or a `Stream` using a library like EPPlus. Then you can serve this using the FileActionResult:

```
public ActionResult CreateExcel()
{
    var data=_repository.GetExcelData();
    byte[] excel=CreateExcelAsByteArray(data);
    return File(excel, "application/vnd.ms-excel", "excel.xlsx");
}
```

With this method you can serve a dinamically created Excel file.

**Update:** To create the excel file you can use EPPlus:

```
public byte[] CreateExcelAsByteArray(IEnumerable<int> elems)
{
    using(var ms=new MemoryStream())
    using(var package=new ExcelPackage())
    {
        var ws = package.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("worksheet");
        int i=1;
        foreach(var elem in elems)
        {
            ws.Cells("A"+i).Value=elem;
            i++;
        }
        package.SaveAs(ms);
        return ms.ToArray();
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a good start but how would i change its values, for example in VB.net I can instantiate the Excel Object and say excel.(linenumber)=thisVariable. Thats kinda what I'm shooting for here, loop through my data and display them as I wish onto an excel.

Comment: Possibly even a HTML file that can be converted out to an Excel? or something around these lines.

Comment: Use a third party library (I wouldn't use the Excel Iterop bindings for a server app. EPPlus is really nice and can be used for commercial apps.